# Sqlite3 выбрать с 5 по 10 запись

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite3

нужно выбрать например с 5 по 10 запись на sqlite3, как это реализовать?

Comment: А limit и offset не работает что ли?

Comment: "SELECT *  FROM Goods WHERE Cat = ? OFFSET (5) ROWS", ( str(message.text), ) ).fetchmany(5) 
Пишет sqlite3.OperationalError: near "OFFSET": syntax error

Comment: Что за `ROWS` в запросе?

Comment: Взял с интернета. Убрал, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Зачем метка mysql?

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос решил сам

`SELECT *  FROM Goods WHERE Cat = ? LIMIT 5 OFFSET (?) ", (str(message.text), 5)  ).fetchall()`